# Why is this regex so incredibly slow for some queries?

Tags: regex, .net-4.5

For a data migration project I need to do basic verification of the format of a long list of short English sentences.

For some reason, a few particular strings are matched *extremely* slowly (up to 90 seconds on my laptop).

I eventually get the expected result from the regex, but I'm curious why this regex is so slow. I cannot figure it out myself.

`^((\()?[0-9a-zäàâèéêçôóû']+(\)(\s|$)|\s|-|\.|\s?/\s?|!|\?)?)+$` `IgnoreCase|Compiled`

(running on .NET 4.5 / C#)

Queries:

`longword longword longword longword ‘a’ and ‘b’`

`longword longword (longword longword).`

For shorter strings it works at normal speed. Replacing `longword` with `word` in the examples above will speed up things a lot. Removing the `.` from the second example will make it work too. Add a few more `longwords` and it can run for the whole day.

Especially the first example puzzles me because the `‘’` characters are not even allowed in the regex.

Comment: I suspect it's because of the optional items inside the group that has  `+` after it. This results in lots of backtracking and retrying.

Comment: @Barmar Is probably right.  Check this article out for a good description of the issue: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: One thing that might speed this up is word boundaries: `#^(?>\(?\b\w+\b(([).!?-]|\s?/)\s)?)+$#i`  I think that's an equivalent statement with word boundaries added (I used \w instead of your long class to make it readable, they mean close enough to the same thing.  But \w permits underscores) and some minor reduction of nested quantifiers.  I also made the main group atomic, so it shouldn't be broken apart for backtracking.

Comment: If you still haven't fixed your problem, could you be more specific about what you're trying to match, replace ..? Eventually give a few examples to run tests on. Thanks.

Comment: @Loamhoof the problem was fixed by waiting for the migration process to finish :) I just didn't understand the theory behind why this particular regex was so slow. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks @FrankieTheKneeMan! Good reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex will be slow to fail because it contains nested quantifiers of a kind that can cause excessive time-consuming backtracking due to the massive number of matching possibilities they create.

The usual culprit for inordinate backtracking is adjacent subpatterns with flexible quantifiers that can both match the same substring, and nested quantifiers are an example of such.

Consider that the regex `(\w+)+` can match the string `"word"` in 8 different ways

```
word            \w{4}
w-ord           \w{1} \w{3}
wo-rd           \w{2} \w{2}
wor-d           \w{3} \w{1}
wo-r-d          \w{2} \w{1} \w{1}
w-or-d          \w{1} \w{2} \w{1}
w-o-rd          \w{1} \w{1} \w{2}
w-o-r-d         \w{1} \w{1} \w{1} \w{1}
```

and the string `"longword"` in 128 ways, and `"verylongword"` in 2048 ways, and it soon becomes clear that the number of possible ways the pattern can match a string of word characters increases exponentially with its length:

```
Math.Pow(2, string.Length - 1)
```

which is why *"replacing longword with word in the examples above will speed up things a lot"*.

And your regex is far more complex than the above, so if the first unmatchable character appears some way into the string, the regex engine will have to backtrack and try a large number of alternative ways to match the string up to that point, before it can be sure a complete match is impossible.

There is nothing in your regex to match the `).` and `‘a’` found in your example strings, so the regex will fail - but it will take a long time to do so as the unmatchable characters appear towards the end of the string.

It can be confirmed that the nested quantifiers are problematic by trying to match for example the string

```
"longword longword longword!"
```

with the apparently simple pattern

```
^([a-z\s]+)+$
```

On my machine it takes over ten seconds for the engine to fail to find a match.
If an optional `\s?` is then added - `^([a-z\s]+\s?)+$` - the time taken doubles.

Your regex has over ten different optional `?` alternatives to consider after every match of the main character class `[]` so that will exacerbate the backtracking similarly.

The solution is to prevent the engine backtracking into what is matched by the subpattern within the outer `()` by making it an atomic group. This can be done by simply adding `?>` after the opening `(`.

```
@"^(?>(\()?[0-9a-zäàâèéêçôóû']+(\)(\s|$)|\s|-|\.|\s?/\s?|!|\?)?)+$"
```

Or equivalently, but perhaps more efficiently

```
@"^(?>\(?[a-z0-9äàâèéêçôóû']+(?:[\s./!?-]|\)(?:\s|$))?)+$"
```

Note that this would still not allow `).` or `)!` etc. which you may want to do.

See [Optimizing Regular Expression Performance, Part II: Taking Charge of Backtracking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/08/03/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-ii-taking-charge-of-backtracking.aspx)